# Combine two Javascript directories into two single, separate files

Tags: javascript, gradle, gradle-plugin

The project I'm working on is using combineJS from [this gradle plugin](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin) in its gradle build. What it does is combine the contents of a directory, in this case topsoil_js, into a single javascript file. I would like to do the same, but with the contents of a different directory, plots_js, into a different single file.

The current code looks like this:

```
javascript.source {
    topsoil {
        js {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources/org/cirdles/topsoil/plot/topsoil_js'
            include '*.js'
        }
    }
    plots {
        js {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources/org/cirdles/topsoil/plot/plots_js'
            include '*js'
        }
    }
}


combineJs {
    source = javascript.source.topsoil.js.files
    dest = file("${project.buildDir}/resources/main/org/cirdles/topsoil/plot/topsoil.js")
}
```

I've tried adding an identical combineJs statement to combine plots_js, like so:

```
combineJs {
    source = javascript.source.plots.js.files
    dest = file("${project.buildDir}/resources/main/org/cirdles/topsoil/plot/plots.js")
}
```

The problem is that `source` and `dest` get overwritten, so only the last combineJs you call actually combines a file. I'm relatively new to gradle, so I'm not actually sure how the rest of the project consumes these variables. Are they keywords that gradle knows to look for, or are they arbitrary?

Most importantly: does anyone have suggestions on how to combine both sets of files?

EDIT: I also tried following the instructions in [this](https://eriwen.github.io/gradle-js-plugin/) documentation for the plugin, which tells me to format it like so:

```
task combineTopsoilJs(type: com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.CombineJsTask) {
    source = javascript.source.topsoil.js.files
    dest = file("${project.buildDir}/resources/main/org/cirdles/topsoil/plot/topsoil.js")
}

task combinePlotJs(type: com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.CombineJsTask) {
    source = javascript.source.plots.js.files
    dest = file("${project.buildDir}/resources/main/org/cirdles/topsoil/plot/BasicPlot.js")
}
```

But this format isn't working either, just throwing an error I'm having trouble tracking down.